# what is some measure-approach introductory book to stochastic processes?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am eager to study stochastic processes in my free time and as I am an  undergraduate student in economics the concepts are completely unfamiliar for me. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm no expert in this field, but [here](http://stat.math.uregina.ca/~kozdron/Teaching/Regina/441Fall14/Notes/index.html) is a set of notes on Stochastic Calculus geared towards people with interests in finance (so their math background may be weaker than traditional math students).

Comment: How much probability do you already know?

Comment: I don't know anything except single and multivariable calculus in mathematics